# FindBoost always fails

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, boost, cmake

I installed **Boost** with `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

I've also tried building and installing it into a custom location as per [the documentation here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#id25), then adding the path in the **Environment Variables** in **nano ~/.bashrc** :

```
## BOOST
export BOOST_ROOT=/home/user/Downloads/boost_1_66_0
export BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR=${BOOST_ROOT}
export BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=${BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib
```

Non of these work. I get the following error when I try building the app with `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../` :

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

This is how the **Boost** set-up looks in **CMakeLists.txt** :

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 

find_package(Boost 1.45.0 COMPONENTS filesystem) 

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    add_executable(progname file1.cxx file2.cxx) 
    target_link_libraries(progname ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

What am I missing? How can I fix it and make it work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm willing to bet real money that the boost project has documentation available regarding this, that you should read.

Comment: Pass additional option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to `cmake`, and look for the files which are searched. Compare these files with ones you actually have.

Comment: You need to build boost using cross-compilation toolchains for android and then provide hints in cmake file to make `find_package` work. Also i should mention that current boost version is 1.80

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake doesn't find Boost libraries while using android-cmake toolchain file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715694/cmake-doesnt-find-boost-libraries-while-using-android-cmake-toolchain-file)

Answer (score 0):

a detailed explanation of how to use Boost with Android and android Studio at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77662372/1756939

with an explanation on how to debug efficiently the findboost.cmake script.

Comment: why didn't you flag to close as a duplicate? (you wrote the linked answer)

Comment: @starball cause I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: [/help/privileges/flag-posts](/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: @starball but I have to say i found a (potential) bug and workaround (and I wrote it on the Android NDK google group) so I can understand why the OP opened this question, this bug preventing it to work may have not been present in earlier versions of cmake used. Here the key is really to understand how to debug FindBoost (that gives always problems), and in this duplicate answer the accent is posed on that. could help to ring the right bell in a way.